# An Olympiad Geometry problem with incenter configurations.

Tags: geometry, contest-math

Let the inscribed circle of triangle ABC touches side BC at D ,side CA at E and side AB at F. Let G be the foot of the perpendicular from D to EF. Show that $\frac{FG}{EG} = \frac{BF}{CE}$.

So this problem is equivalent to proving similarity between $\Delta BFG$ and $\Delta CEG$.

I was able to prove that $\angle GFB$ = $\angle GEC$ but after that, I hit a dead end. I found the point $G$ pretty annoying as I couldn't apply any circle theorems to it.[image]

Any solution is highly appreciated but I am not very good at inversion and complex numbers so please don't use them.

Comment: Your mistake is drawing an almost isosceles triangle and confusing G lies on AD. AD is NOT the angle bisector.

Comment: @cosmo5 yes I realize that AD is not angle bisector, it is IA that is angle bisector

Comment: @cosmo5 so if i can not use similarity, I am kind of stuck. Would you please be kind enough to give me a hint as to how to proceed, ie. which lengths are known.

Comment: Each side is divided into two segments which are tangents to incircle, whose lengths are well known.

Comment: I have a solution, but it uses some advanced techniques. The idea is to let $(AEF)$ meet $(ABC)$ again at $P$, then you can show that $\triangle PBF\sim\triangle PDG\sim\triangle PCE$ and so $PFGE\sim PBDC$ from which the ratios pop out

Comment: @cosmo5 We do have $ \angle GFB = \angle GEC$. They are both equal to $ 90 ^ \circ + ( 180^ \circ - \angle FIE ) /2  =90 ^\circ +  \alpha / 2$.

Comment: @CalvinLin My bad, I was looking at $\angle GFD$ and $\angle GED$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Triangle ABC]

Draw $DE$, $DF$, $IB$ and $IC$.

Observe that, $\angle GED=\angle FED=90-\frac{\angle B}{2}=\angle BID$ and $\angle EGD=\angle IDB=90^{\circ}$; Hence, $\triangle EGD\sim \triangle IDB$.  Similarly, one can yield,  $\triangle FGD\sim \triangle IDC$.

Thus, $\frac{FG}{GD}=\frac{ID}{DC}$ and $\frac{EG}{GD}=\frac{ID}{BD}$.

Dividing these ratios gives, $\frac{FG}{EG}=\frac{BD}{DC}=\frac{BF}{CE}$  [Since $BD=BF$ and $DC=CE$]

Comment: Oh nice, I didn't draw the connection that those triangles were similar (which is obvious in hindsight). I was just focused on calculating those ratios.

Comment: I have added a diagram.

Comment: Nice answer! If the cropping border of the image is as small as possible, the diagram will appear bigger.

Comment: @cosmo5 Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Thanks so much for this, really appreciate it

Comment: @Aditya_math  Glad that you liked it.

Answer (score 2):

(Fill in the gaps as needed. If you're stuck, show your work and what you've tried.)

Just direct angle chasing and trigo will help you express those ratios.

- Show that $BF /CE  = BD / DC = (BD / DG) / (DC / DG) = \tan ( 90^\circ - \beta /2)  / \tan (90^\circ - \gamma / 2) = \tan \gamma/2 / \tan \beta/2 $
- Show that $ \angle IFE = \angle IAE  = \alpha / 2 $.
- Show that $ FG / GE = (FG / GD) / (GE / GD) = \tan \gamma/2 / \tan \beta/2 $ .

Comment: thanks, before finishing reading the answer, when I saw $tan$ I understood the approach  and then solved it. Thanks so much for this solution